# Поиск подстроки в начале и конце строки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: python, python-3.x, re, bool

Задача:

Имеется игра «Саймон говорит». Инструктор «Саймон» говорит, что должны делать игроки в инструкции. Напишите функцию, которая принимает строку с инструкциями:

1. Если она **начинается** или **заканчивается** словами "Simon says";
2. Ваша функция должна возвращать строку "I" плюс то, что вы бы сделали: сами инструкции;
3. В противном случае верните "I won't do it!" .

Вы НЕ должны обрабатывать ввод или вызывать свою функцию, просто реализуйте ее.

С помощью regex101.com я описала первую часть функции:

```
^\s*(Simon says)
```

- фраза начинается с "Simon says";

```
(Simon says)\s*$
```

- фраза заканчивается "Simon says"

Но...я не знаю, как их вместе слепить Как мне их объединить, чтоб корректно работали?!

Код целиком с корявым регулярным выражением:

```
import re
phrase = r"^\s*(Simon says)(тут должно что-то быть) (Simon says)\s*$"
def what_to_do(instructions):
    if bool(re.fullmatch(phrase, instructions)):
        return("I" + instructions)
    else:
        return("I won't do it!")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не обязательно использовать регулярные выражения, чтобы выполнить эту задачу. Вы можете использовать методы строк `.startswith()` и `.endswith()`:

```
def what_to_do(instructions):
  if instructions.startswith("Simon says"):
    return("I " + instructions[10:])
  elif instructions.endswith("Simon says"):
    return("I " + instructions[:-10])
  else:
      return("I won't do it!")

print(what_to_do("Simon says jump!"))
print(what_to_do("Please, jump!"))
```

Метод с использованием регулярных выражений:

```
import re

r = "(Simon says .*)|(.* Simon says)"

def what_to_do(instructions):
    if bool(re.fullmatch(r, instructions)):
        return("I " + re.sub("\s*Simon says\s*", "", instructions))
    else:
        return("I won't do it!")

print(what_to_do("Simon says jump!"))
print(what_to_do("Please, jump!"))
```

Объяснение регулярного выражения:

`(Simon says .*)|(.* Simon says)`

1. Структура `()|()` - выполняется условие либо в первой скобке, либо во второй.
2. `*.` - Любое количество любых символов, в том числе и пробельных.

Comment: да, таким способом я уже задачу решила, (но все равно большое спасибо),однако он, во-первых, неинтересный, во-вторых, мне очень хочется освоить регулярки. Пока не поддаются...((( Или просто я тупая, как вариант.

Comment: Понял вас, сейчас напишу способ с регулярными выражениями.

Comment: Ответ обновил, @ВикаМельникова

Comment: Благодарю))) Особенно для меня ценно объяснение регулярного выражения!!!